# Laptop samsung 700z3a runs out of battery too soon despite high capacity

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an old laptop `samsung 700z3a` from approximately 2012. It runs out of battery within 2-2.5 hours without heavy load. However, the battery is alive according to Power Manager: [pic which shows that battery's capacity is at 86% of the designed one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmiFb.png) . The OS *was* Windows 7, I then replaced it with Debian 11, but the problem remains. Any idea what could be causing this? Or is it natural for this laptop?

Given:

- Model: Samsung 700Z3A laptop
- OS: Debian 11
- Capacity: 56 Wh (designed: 65 Wh)
- It works until it reaches 3%, then shuts down. So I guess that's another confirmation that the battery is fine.

Comment: Did you replace the original battery?

Comment: I don't remember, to be honest. But if I did, what then could be a problem?

Comment: Old batteries lose their charge much faster the new ones even if they are still working.

Comment: Isn't it because their capacity is low, though? Which is not my case

Comment: No, it is not because of low capacity, its because of fatigue of materials.

Comment: I see. How can I check it? And will replacement help? Also, how long my laptop should work for (I couldn't find any info on that), do you think?

Comment: IMHO the replace will help. The manufacturer promises a runtime of up to 7 hours, but this depend a lot from the usage. Heavy apps like photo, video editors, may drain the batter much faster.

Comment: @WhiteBlackGoose https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Samsung-Series-7-700Z3A-S03DE-Notebook.69245.0.html claims "up to" 7 hours, presumably running nothing but the OS (no other apps) and with the screen on minimal brightness.

Answer (score 0):

If the original battery is not replaced this looks for me like battery is too old and can't keep the charge. This can be because of fatigue of materials. Do not forget charger measure battery charge w/o a load so you can't rely much on this.
The manufacturer promises a runtime of up to 7 hours, but this depend a lot from the usage. Heavy apps like photo, video editors, may drain the batter much faster. So battery replacement should help you.